# Display adds video between main video

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have a android app that play video from server in `VideoView`. Now I want to play some adds video from my server between my main video like `youtube`. How can I achieve this approach.

Comment: what you have tried so far ? any error

Comment: @Sree I want play some other adds video between my main video. I think you understand my question. I have no idea for implement this thing. I just want to know to achieve this need

Comment: for that you can create a logic which will load add video in the time duration

Comment: @Sree can you provide some helpful link or any hints?

Comment: @shaileshojha you should start from your side first and then if you face any difficulty or issue then post here for resolved it

Answer (score 2):

you can pause your video, get current position, remember it, load ADS video, load your video again after ADS finishes, and set the playback position to the remembered one

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I am start working according your suggestion